# SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Long?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am doing something like:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS field1
```

In SQL. This however is a `Timestamp` type field, is there a way to get it as a `Long`?

Comment: And what would that long value represent (seconds since epoch, milliseconds since epoch, or since the epoch used by the database system)? A SQL `TIMESTAMP` as returned by `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a date+time, not just a long value. To derive a long value, we need to know what value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use modern classes, not terrible `Timestamp`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( 1 , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
long millisecondsFromEpoch = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

Comment: With that 'terrible' `Timestamp`, you can use `Timestamp.getTime()`, and `getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class)` only works for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` types, not for `TIMESTAMP (WITHOUT TIME ZONE)` types (or at least, JDBC 4.2 only defines `OffsetDateTime` support for `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` not for `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeStamp.getTime() method to get you result in long.

Example:
long timeStampLong = timeStamp.getTime();